# Context free Grammar for Simile

Tags: python, nlp, context-free-grammar, opennlp

I am working on a Project ,and need help with building a context free grammar for Simile(parts of speech) . If anyone can tell me where to start or give me some hints!

the work done

## The grammar used to check a simile

```
grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP "like" NP | "JJ" "like" "NP" | NP V "like" NP | "EX" "like" "NN" | NP "as" "JJ" "as" NP | V "as" "JJ" "as" NP | "as" NP "as"| OTH
NP -> N | "JJ" N | "DT" NP | "NNS" N
N -> "NNP" | "PRP" | "NN"
V -> "VBD" | "VB" | "VBG"
OTH -> "OTH" "PUNC" "FW" "WDT" "TO" "RB" "VBD" "VBG"  "LS" "VBN" "NN" "IN" "S" "EX" "VB" "CC" "UH" "PRP" "MD" 
""")
```

this is made with brute force approach,

Comment: You should always start by telling us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have shared it now  thanks .